# Selenium htmlsuite report is not created

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I stored all my test cases with test suite in the following path in my machine.

```
/home/mrblack/gtest/*
```

I run the following command in my terminal everything is working fine. But, the report file is  still empty. Can any one help me how to get report file?.

```
java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com" "/home/mrblack/gtest/gts" "/tmp/result.html"
```

I used very simple suite file only.

test case: http://justpaste.it/mrbtc_goo
test sutie: http://justpaste.it/mrbts_goo

Comment: did you ever sort this out? I spent the entire day trying to get the report... ran out of ideas.

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer part below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution.. I executed the following line from the current directory of selenium-server.jar file.  It works for me

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com" "gts" "result.html"
```